How can I post a message to an iframe loaded later without violating CORS policies?
I need to send a message to an iframe that is loaded after a user clicks a link.
The nature of the error message makes me believe that this is Javascript that is angry and not nginx.  It seems like it didn't even attempt the postMessage.
javascript console
(index):6 loading site2 iframe ...
(index):8 sending message from site1 to site2 ...
(index):9 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://site2.example.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://site1.example.com').

site1.example.com/index.html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadIFrame() {
        console.log( "loading site2 iframe ..." );
        document.getElementById('myiframe').src = "http://site2.example.com";
        console.log( "sending message from site1 to site2 ..." );
        document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.postMessage( "Hello World!", 'http://site2.example.com');
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Site1</h2>

    <a href="#" onclick="loadIFrame()">load iframe</a>
    <br/><br/><br/>

    <iframe id="myiframe" style="width:600px; height: 400ps;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>

site2.example.com/index.html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener( 'message', event => {
    if ( event.origin === 'http://site1.example.com' ) {
      const item = event.data;
      console.log( "site2 received message: " + item );
    }
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Site2</h2>

<body>
</html>

site1.example.com nginx config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.example.com;

    location / {
        root /home/user/test-sites/site1;

    }
}

site2.example.com nginx config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.example.com;

    set $cors "";
    if ($http_origin ~* (.*\.example.com)) {
        set $cors "true";
    }

    location / {
        root /home/user/test-sites/site2;

        if ($cors = "true") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
        }

        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}

I should also mention that this header shows up in site2.example.com within the iframe
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

I'm not sure if that should be different given my attempted configuration.

Neither CORS nor Referrer Policy is relevant for postMessage.

My understanding is that http://site2.example.com hasn't had enough time to load in your iframe when you attempt to send a message to it; you're still on http://site1.example.com at that stage.

It was indeed a problem with properly identifying when the loading was complete.  The following works:
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadIFrame() {
        var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
        myIframe.addEventListener( "load", function() {
            console.log( "sending message from site1 to site2 ..." );
            this.contentWindow.postMessage( "Hello World!", 'http://site2.example.com');
        });
        console.log( "loading site2 iframe ..." );
        myIframe.src = "http://site2.example.com";
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Site1</h2>

    <a href="#" onclick="loadIFrame()">load iframe</a>
    <br/><br/><br/>

    <iframe id="myIframe" style="width:600px; height: 400ps;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>

